# How to set public textview in activity from fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to set the text of textview in activity from a fragment. This is how I do it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public TextView textViewNotification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        textViewNotification = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_notification));
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PIT IAI & FIP Regional");

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.notification.setText("This is a test"); // => got error here.

        return root;
    }
}
```

But it didin't work. This is the error that I got:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5846)
```

How is it exactly to get and set public attributes of activity from fragments? is it not possible? Please help.

Comment: move "This is a test" to string resources and replace it with R.string.test

Answer (score 2):

Supposed you want to send the text to the activity based on some action.

You can use an interface, first create a public interface in your fragment and add one method inside it which takes one string parameter

```
public interface CommunicateWithActivity{
   void onCommunicate(String s)
 }
```

, declare a global variable mListener of type CommunicateWithActivity,

```
private CommunicateWithActivity mListener;
```

then  override onAttach and inside try/catch block

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (CommunicateWithActivity) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "CommunicateWithActivity implementation in Activity is required");
        }

    }
```

then in the activity implement the interface an override "onComunicate(String s)" method in the activity and you will get your string inside the methd.

```
@Override
    public void onCommunicate(String s) {
      //do whatever you want
    }
```

Comment: It is better to take it from a constructor. That way it allows the user to use multiple instances of the fragment in the same activity. Rare case, but simple to read and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Henry Gunawan your MainActivity does not have any public field called notification you actually named it textViewNotification.

Moreover i am seeing some bad practices in your code

1. Avoid declaring public fields instead use getters and setters to access them
2. Your fragment assuming that it's host is always a MainActivity instance and it has a field called notification , which is not a good practice , fragments are meant to be a standalone unit, fragments should not depends on specifics of their host activity as they may be host by any activity hence this is a misuse of fragments, use should instead use callbacks if you want your host activity to do something for you as explained by Amr Sakr.